# LGA1156 Cooler compatability

Tags: cooling, computer-building, cpu-cooler

Are coolers that are compatible with LGA socket 1356 / 1366 / 2011 / 2011-3 also compatible with LGA1156?

I cant find an answer to that though picture from motherboards see similar and I suppose new FANS dont have the "LGA1156" mentioned as supported because its an old design.

In particular I am interested in learning if Noctua NH-U9DX i4 would be compatible with my i5 750 cpu

Comment: Yes;  They are compatible.  [Example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA9PV3Y61194&cm_re=LGA1156_Cooler-_-35-608-041-_-Product) clearly supports both LGA1356 and LGA1156

Comment: yea but maybe it has different mounting brackets that have to be changed for each LGA but if I buy something else that sais it supports e.g 1366 but hasnt the special brackets for 1156 then what? :P I would hope find the screw distances for those sockets to be absolutely sure :)

Comment: What special brackets are you talking about?  Do you even know, what your talking about, even exists?  You asked a "Yes" or "No" question, you are simply said, making it far to complicated of a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Any** Noctua cooler which comes with the SecuFirm2™ Mounting Kit can support LGA1156.

[image]

Relevant section of the Noctua NH-U9DX i4 specificatins here:

[image]

[Noctua NH-U9DX i4](http://noctua.at/en/nh-u9dx-i4)

It is worth pointing out that you can purchase other mounting kits which are compatiable with **ALL** of their products.

- NM-I3 Mounting-Kit
- NM-i115x Mounting-Kit
- NM-I2011 Mounting-Kit

So the **cooler** itself is fully compatible.  You just have to use the correct mounting kit if the cooler you purchase doesn't come with it.

Comment: I do realize the description of the `SecuFirm2` mounting system makes mention of a different cooler.  The point of the description is to highlight the fact, the mounting system, has not actually changed.  All you need for it to work is the correct mounting-kit.  What evidence do I have to support this, its the fact I have used the same Noctua cooler (in other words the same cooler I purchased), for nearly every hardware I have done in the past 4 years across both Core and Xeon products.